# How to format output to two decimal places and '$' symbol in C#?

Tags: c#, string-formatting

Newbie to the C# language and 
I just finished creating a loan mortgage calculator and I am having trouble formatting my code below.  What I am trying to do is format the monthly payment value to 2 decimal places and add the '$' symbol. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Example input for my principle amount:

```
//User input for Principle amount in dollars
Console.Write("Enter the loan amount, in dollars(0000.00): ");
principleInput = Console.ReadLine();
principle = double.Parse(principleInput);
//Prompt the user to reenter any illegal input
        if (principle < 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The value for the mortgage cannot be a negative value");
            principle = 0;
        }



//Calculate the monthly payment

double loanM = (interest / 1200.0);
double numberMonths = years * 12;
double negNumberMonths = 0 - numberMonths;
double monthlyPayment = principle * loanM / (1 - System.Math.Pow((1 + loanM),    negNumberMonths));




//Output the result of the monthly payment
        Console.WriteLine("The amount of the monthly payment is: " + monthlyPayment);
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Press the Enter key to end. . .");
        Console.Read();
```

Answer (score 11):

> What I am trying to do is format the monthly payment value to 2 decimal places and add the '$' symbol.

It sounds like you want to use the [currency format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#CFormatString).

```
Console.WriteLine("The amount of the monthly payment is: {0:c}", monthlyPayment);
```

That won't always use the dollar symbol of course - it will use the currency symbol for the thread's current culture. You can always specify `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` explicitly.

However, I'd strongly advise you *not* to use `double` for currency values. Use `decimal` instead.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that the decimal format is more suited than a double when it comes to monetary values. (Also for the right answer :D)

Answer (score 1):

[From MSDN: Standard Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx)
(look for 'The Currency ("C") Format Specifier')

Console.WriteLine("The amount of the monthly payment is: {0:C2} ", monthlyPayment);

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`Math.Round()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s2d3xkk.aspx) function:

```
double inputNumber = 90.0001;
string outputNumber = "$" + Math.Round(inputNumber, 2).ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

To use 2 decimal places you can use:

```
Console.WriteLine("The amount of the monthly payment is: "$ " + Math.Round(monthlyPayment,2));
```